# Очередь в postgresql

Tags: postgresql, очередь

У меня есть проект, который активно работает с postgresql, возникла необходимость в очередях (отложенных задачах).
Какой наилучший способ реализации этого в postgres? (Писать свое решение, или использовать какое-нибудь готовое расширение)

Спасибо.

Comment: в postgres есть планировщики, можно создавать задание для них.

Comment: @МихаилКетов, вы имеете в виду это https://habr.com/ru/post/456722/ ? Мне нужно немного другое, например, отправка email уведомлений. (как я понял это позволяет лишь выполнять SQL запросы внутри БД)

Comment: можно сделать таблицу с необходимыми для задачи данными и временем следующего выполнения. и внешний процесс обработчик, который ее читает и выполняет в заданное время. если текущей работы нет процесс смотрит когда будет следующее событие и спит до этого времени. Сон можно сделать прерываемым например по нотификациям postgresql (listen/notify), которые посылать из триггера изменяющего расписание

Comment: @Mike, а нету готовых решений? Я например что-то слышал о PGQ, но не нашел документации в интернете...

Comment: Наверняка есть. но такие вещи для эффективной работы должны быть заточены под задачу. Универсальный планировщик наверняка сможет запускать внешние задачи. но если работ много запуск отдельных процессов слишком накладно. Так что лучше бы библиотеку для того языка, на котором у вас приложение сделано. А дальше надо еще смотреть род выполняемых задач. Например если они в основном общаются по сети, то эффективно делать их асинхронными и выполнять сразу помногу в одном потоке. А если расчетные - то отдельные потоки. И если готовая библиотека есть не факт что она делает так как надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено испрользовать PgQ https://github.com/pgq (да, проблемы с документацией, но он надежный и быстрый)